# How do I switch flex theme in flashdevelop?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, themes, flashdevelop

Flex SDK has many great included themes (in swc) as cobalt/arcade/graphite/etc but after hours of Google I still couldn't get how to use them. So how do I change the default theme and use some of included sdk themes or any custom theme in flashdevelop?

Comment: With the command line compiler, you can specify the theme argument to the compiler: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html .  The themes should be included as part of your Flex SDK directory.  I do not know how this is exposed using FlashDevelop, though.

Comment: Thank you, i read about compiler options before but couldn't understand the right syntax and steps to do. But now i finally understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! If someone would face this question too here is the simple solution:

1. Go to project properties->compiler options->additional compiler
   options
2. Add the following compiler option:

   -theme lib/arcade.swc

Where 'lib/arcade.swc' is the path to your swc theme based on project directory (i just put swc into lib directory).